# Translation of the sentence from a cover of a book

Tags: grammar

"THE HISTORICAL ANTIDOTE TO WHAT ISN'T WORKING TODAY" I found this sentence on a cover of a book.I do not think that the sentence is not the same as "the historical antidote which is not working today".It means that the antidote from the past for something which is not working at present.Right?

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct.

Comment: an antidote to sth. -> A medicine to counteract a particular poison or unpleasant thing. e.g.: An antidote to the poison. I believe in this sentence the "poison" is "things that aren't working today" and the "antidote" is a historical one.